# How to send money abroad from India if the transaction does not fall under LRS scheme?

Tags: money-transfer

I would d like to send a small amount (about USD 100) to a person living in Turkey for some freelance work. I found some sites like sites like XendPay, FxKart that allows you to transfer money abroad from India. But these sites allows you to transfer money only to your family member or a close relative under Liberalised Remittance Scheme (LRS). PayPal is no longer working in Turkey.

Is there any other way to send money abroad from India when the recipient is not our close relative? Do Indian banks allow such transactions?

Comment: I use Transferwise to send money from Brazil to Chile. Check if they operate in both countries

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Currently Transerwise allow transferring INR 20000 (about USD 266) as the smallest amount. But, I usually send payments less than $150. And, there are chances that they will also restrict the money transfer to a person who is not your close relative.

Btw, they already closed this question as "Off Topic." What's wrong with these guys? If they have authority they will close the question even before it gets published on the site.